# Is it safe to use `Const-Generic` structure in runtime storage?

Tags: runtime, storage

When declare `pubkeys` field as `generic-const-array` [here](https://github.com/Snowfork/snowbridge/blob/849e218b17597a11cd7e43b78b52ee14d1c936b2/parachain/primitives/beacon/src/types.rs#L182-L186) as following

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
pub struct SyncCommitteePrepared<const COMMITTEE_SIZE: usize> {
    pub pubkeys: [PublicKeyPrepared; COMMITTEE_SIZE],
    pub aggregate_pubkey: PublicKeyPrepared,
}
```

benchmark failed with `wasm trap: out of bounds memory access` as following when tring to retrieve and decode.

```
Error: Input("Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: out of bounds memory access\n

WASM backtrace:\n
error while executing at wasm backtrace:\n
    0: 0x4aac8c - <unknown>!compiler_builtins::mem::memcpy::ha7ae349bf234661d\n
    1: 0x4aa7a3 - <unknown>!memcpy\n
    2: 0x3581a7 - <unknown>!snowbridge_beacon_primitives::types::_::<impl parity_scale_codec::codec::Decode for snowbridge_beacon_primitives::types::SyncCommitteePrepared<_>>::decode::hd88776f59538a9b9\n
    3: 0x300d2c - <unknown>!frame_support::storage::types::map::StorageMap<Prefix,Hasher,Key,Value,QueryKind,OnEmpty,MaxValues>::get::h7f1c3a10c693c8aa\n
    4: 0xfdf86 - <unknown>!snowbridge_ethereum_beacon_client::pallet::Pallet<T>::sync_committee_for_period::hbc4920725666ac12\n
    5: 0x100e9b - <unknown>!snowbridge_ethereum_beacon_client::pallet::Pallet<T>::process_sync_committee_period_update::h9d8f30544088a699\n
    6: 0x2d92e8 - <unknown>!frame_support::storage::transactional::with_transaction::hb1d1c484c1750f74\n
    7: 0x338a69 - <unknown>!<snowbridge_ethereum_beacon_client::pallet::Call<T> as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::{{closure}}::hf8a2139be9c19e40\n
    8: 0x33b8cc - <unknown>!environmental::local_key::LocalKey<T>::with::h2be8bf922186fc4d\n
    9: 0x25a42a - <unknown>!core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h369b9896735a8a64\n
   10: 0xf8648 - <unknown>!snowbridge_ethereum_beacon_client::benchmarking::<impl frame_benchmarking::utils::Benchmarking for snowbridge_ethereum_beacon_client::pallet::Pallet<T>>::run_benchmark::h5569c44f915b68d6\n
   11: 0x1bdc21 - <unknown>!<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime as frame_benchmarking::utils::runtime_decl_for_benchmark::BenchmarkV1<sp_runtime::generic::block::Block<sp_runtime::generic::header::Header<u32,sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256>,sp_runtime::generic::unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<sp_runtime::multiaddress::MultiAddress<<<sp_runtime::MultiSignature as sp_runtime::traits::Verify>::Signer as sp_runtime::traits::IdentifyAccount>::AccountId,()>,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::RuntimeCall,sp_runtime::MultiSignature,(frame_system::extensions::check_non_zero_sender::CheckNonZeroSender<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::BridgeRejectObsoleteHeadersAndMessages,(bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::RefundBridgedParachainMessages<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime,bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::RefundableParachain<frame_support::instances::Instance2,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_wococo_config::BridgeHubRococoParachainId>,bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::RefundableMessagesLane<frame_support::instances::Instance2,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_wococo_config::BridgeHubRococoMessagesLane>,bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::ActualFeeRefund<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_wococo_config::PriorityBoostPerMessage,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_wococo_config::StrBridgeRefundBridgeHubRococoMessages>,bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::RefundBridgedParachainMessages<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime,bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::RefundableParachain<frame_support::instances::Instance1,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_rococo_config::BridgeHubWococoParachainId>,bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::RefundableMessagesLane<frame_support::instances::Instance1,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_rococo_config::BridgeHubWococoMessagesLane>,bridge_runtime_common::refund_relayer_extension::ActualFeeRefund<bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::Runtime>,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_rococo_config::PriorityBoostPerMessage,bridge_hub_rococo_runtime::bridge_hub_rococo_config::StrBridgeRefundBridgeHubWococoMessages>))>>>>::dispatch_benchmark::h9cf508cd5091e662\n
   12: 0x2657ff - <unknown>!Benchmark_dispatch_benchmark")
```

Just resolved when change to `BoundedVec` in this [commit](https://github.com/Snowfork/snowbridge/commit/22274fad4e604152a347fc03cfb9eefea28fbc6b) as following

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(MaxCommitteeSize))]
pub struct SyncCommitteePrepared<MaxCommitteeSize: Get<u32>> {
    pub pubkeys: BoundedVec<PublicKeyPrepared, MaxCommitteeSize>,
    pub aggregate_pubkey: PublicKeyPrepared,
}
```

Hope someone can help to confirm is it safe to use `Const-Generic` structure in runtime storage as above?

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? So you just store the type in the storage and load it?

Comment: @bkchr Yes, just store/load a big object array. Add an issue https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/14075 for more detail.

Comment: The first panic that you posted was in `storage_map_final_key`, which would be very concerning and has nothing to do with the const generics. Anyway, good that it is resolved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it wasn't really a Substrate issue.

Comment: @bkchr Add some more clues here
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/14075#issuecomment-1536972765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade toolchain to `nightly-2023-04-22`.

also addressed by https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec/pull/426